# Removing Annotation causes NullPointerException when redrawing

Tags: nullpointerexception, achartengine

I am using `achartengine` and I am getting NullPointerException when removing an annotation and then adding it again with differents (x,y) values. Here is the code:

```
for(int n = 0; n < series.getAnnotationCount(); ++n){
    double x = toCoordinate(series.getAnnotationX(n)*prevTimeScale*1000, timeScale);
    double y = series.getAnnotationY(n);
    String text = series.getAnnotationAt(n);

    series.removeAnnotation(n);
    series.addAnnotation(n, text, x, y);
}
```

The `addAnnotation()` method with index doesn't exists in the current ace framework but I have added it:

```
public void addAnnotation(int index, String annotation, double x, double y) {
    mAnnotations.add(index, annotation);
    mStringXY.put(index, x, y);
}
```

Basically I remove an Annotation at a given index and then I add the same text but with different coordinates. After calling `GraphicalView#repaint()` I get this `NullPointerException`:

```
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getAnnotationY(XYSeries.java:294)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:310)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:177)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13717)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:12971)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12634)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13433)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12653)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12593)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12593)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12593)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12593)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2910)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12593)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12699)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2173)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
07-23 19:41:56.256: E/AndroidRuntime(17984):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 19:42:03.088: E/Trace(18186): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

The problem is in the method `getAnnotationY(int index)` which uses `getYByIndex(int index)` in `IndexXYMap`:

```
public V getYByIndex(int index) {
  K key = indexList.get(index);
  return this.get(key);
}
```

because the line `return this.get(key)` is returning `null` and I don't know why because I am adding the annotation with the index. I am using the latest ace version from SVN repository.

What could be causing the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: for new in android as me `public void removeAnnotation(int index) {
    mAnnotations.remove(index);
    mStringXY.removeByIndex(index);
  }` in which `mAnnotations` will auto adjust it's content,so if we delete the first annotation, all other annotation's index is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems something not possible with the current API. To do this I have slightly modified the source code. Add this method on `IndexXYMap.java`:

```
  public V set(int index, K key, V value){
    indexList.set(index, key);
    updateMaxXDifference();
    return super.put(key, value);
  }
```

And this method to replace the Annotation at `XYSeries.java`:

```
  /**
   * Replaces an Annotation at the given index
   * 
   * @param index annotation index
   * @param annotation new String to put
   * @param x new x coordinate to use
   * @param y new y coordinate to use
   */
  public void replaceAnnotation(int index, String annotation, double x, double y){
    mAnnotations.set(index, annotation);
    mStringXY.set(index, x, y);
  }
```

So now to replace an Annotation you have to use this method:

```
replaceAnnotation(index, "New Text", newX, newY);
```

Answer (score 0):

after get achartengine via snv i think Removing Annotation and add new cause exception may be because `XYSeries`'s `clear` calls `clearAnnotations()` is
`public synchronized void clearAnnotations() {
   mStringXY.clear();
  }`
add `mAnnotations.clear();` before `mStringXY.clear();`  it seems a bug.